# How to view the source code for the encryption and decryption functions in php?

Tags: php, xampp, mcrypt

I want to view the source code for the various encryption and decryption functions used by PHP . How can I do so? I use Xampp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You download [the source code](http://php.net/downloads.php#v5) from the PHP site and examine that.

Also it's searchable and indexed online: http://lxr.php.net/